# Android: Resources$NotFoundException: String resource 0#00 on list view item click

Tags: android, exception

Here's the `Adapter` source code which extends `BaseAdapter` and contains multiple views.

```
public class AddNewAlarmOptionItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int ITEM_TEXT_ONLY = 0;
    private static final int ITEM_TEXT_AND_PROGRESS_BAR = 1;
    private static final int ITEM_TEXT_AND_SWITCH = 2;

    // number of types in total.
    private static final int ITEM_TOTAL_TYPES = 3;

    private ArrayList<AddNewAlarmOptionItem> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public AddNewAlarmOptionItemListAdapter() {

    }

    // overridden method for enabling the adapter to contain different types of views.
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return ITEM_TOTAL_TYPES;
    }

    // overridden method for enabling the adapter to contain different types of views.
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return itemLists.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemLists.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        AddNewAlarmOptionItem item = itemLists.get(position);

        switch(viewType) {
            case ITEM_TEXT_ONLY:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_text_only, viewGroup, false);
                TextView tvSubject = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                TextView tvOptions = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtitle);
                tvSubject.setText(item.getTitle());
                tvOptions.setText(item.getSubtitle());
                break;

            case ITEM_TEXT_AND_PROGRESS_BAR:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_text_and_seek_bar, viewGroup, false);
                TextView tvAlarmType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmType);
                TextView tvAlarmOption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmOption);

                tvAlarmType.setText(item.getTitle());
                tvAlarmOption.setText(item.getSubtitle());

                ImageView ivSpeaker = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivSpeaker);
                SeekBar sbVolume = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sbVolume);

                break;

            case ITEM_TEXT_AND_SWITCH:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_text_and_switch, viewGroup, false);
                TextAndSwitchItem textAndSwitchItem = new TextAndSwitchItem();
                TextView tvAlarmOptionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmOptionTitle);
                TextView tvAlarmOptionDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOptionDescription);
                Switch switchOption = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switchOption);
                tvAlarmOptionTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
                tvAlarmOptionDescription.setText(item.getSubtitle());
                switchOption.setChecked(true);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    // add a text-only item to list view
    public void addItem(TextOnlyItem item) {
        item.setType(ITEM_TEXT_ONLY);
        itemLists.add(item);
    }

    // add a text-and-progress-bar item to list view
    public void addItem(TextAndSeekbarItem item) {
        item.setType(ITEM_TEXT_AND_PROGRESS_BAR);
        itemLists.add(item);
    }

    // add a text-and-switch item to list view
    public void addItem(TextAndSwitchItem item) {
        item.setType(ITEM_TEXT_AND_SWITCH);
        itemLists.add(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the part of an `Activity` which contains the list and the `onItemClickListener`.

```
listAdapter = new AddNewAlarmOptionItemListAdapter();
        lvAlarmOptionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAlarmOptionList);
        lvAlarmOptionList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        tpTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tpTimePicker);

        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cancelAddingNewAlarm();
            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveAlarm();
            }
        });

        initializeListItems();
        addItemsToListView();

        lvAlarmOptionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateNewAlarmActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

When I ran this code, I expected that the Toast message would appear with the corresponding position number, but it crashed with this message - `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`.

Comment: it is because toast can not inflate int values. You should use  String.valueOf(position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
Toast.makeText(CreateNewAlarmActivity.this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

From your code, you are trying to toast the position of item click in listview.
But Toast accepts a message in `String` resource to display.

Answer (score 0):

This is common mistake for most of the developers, will do for toast.

Toast.makeText has two versions

1st method will take context, resourceid -> Integer, duration

```
            Toast.makeText(context, resource, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

2nd method will take context, string message, duration

```
            Toast.makeText(context, resource, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In your case your passing position, so it will call 1st method, it will look for any resource with id 0, that will not found so it will throw Resources$NotFoundException.

**Solution:**

```
Toast.makeText(context, string.valueof(resource), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 lvAlarmOptionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateNewAlarmActivity.this, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```